# Can not dowloand and install python for Busybox Allwinner F113

Tags: python, linux, wget, busybox

I am using Allwinner F113 (MangoPi MQ-R board) and it includes Tina-Linux(BusyBox). I want to dowloand python but wget keeps giving error response.

```
root@TinaLinux:/# wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.1/Python-3.9.1.tgz
wget: not an http or ftp url: https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.1/Python-3.9.1.tgz
```

Then I wanted to dump this .tgz file into root sd card but it is write protected. Although it's not protected, I honestly don't know where to put it.

This is file system:
[allwinner file system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xMO1.png)

How can i dowloand and install python ?

I tried wget command and it was not work. And the file system is write protected.

Answer (score -1):

> How can i dowloand and install python ?

Generally most linux distrubtions have some [Package Manager](https://www.tecmint.com/linux-package-managers/) installed, I do not know which one is specific for

> Allwinner F113 (MangoPi MQ-R board) and it includes
> Tina-Linux(BusyBox)

but I suggest to first trying installation `python` via package manager.

Comment: Busybox has not a package manager. my problem is not being able to download any files. so i can't download python.